# Error when add implementation for gradle to add ads

Tags: java, android, gradle, implementation

I would like to add ads from ADmob The problem is when i add implementation for gradle the program stops working once you open it in any phone or emulator What is the solution ..?

the list of ERROR is :

12-06 11:24:45.656 1786-1786/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ads, PID: 1786
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4777)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxw.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:27)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The question is closed, although it differs from the one you say is similar

Comment: Ok i Edit the question and include the error message

Comment: Have you read the link at the bottom?

Comment: I don't speak English very well can you please send me the link 

Comment: Okay. What tutorial have you followed to get ads in your app? Because it requires more than just one line of Gradle